# Не получается добавить cordova-plugin-file в Phonegap проект

Tags: плагин, phonegap, cordova

Пытаюсь добавить плагин "file" в Phonegap проект, получаю ошибки:

```
d:\Android\projects\myProject>phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-file
Error: Failed to fetch plugin git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm WARN cordova-plugin-camera@2.1.1 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@>=2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.5.1 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN cordova-plugin-media-capture@1.2.0 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN com.phonegap.helloworld@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN com.phonegap.helloworld@1.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Что я делаю не так?

п.с: работаю на Windows, версия Phonegap 7.0.1